TYPO3 Powermail: select with multiple identical values
In TYPO3 11.5.37, Powermail 10.9.0 (current version, but also with our previous one 10.7.0) I can not use select-fields with multiple options with the same value. Whenever I define multiple options with the same value, only the last one gets rendered:
//field settings:
mango | fruit
rose | flower
pineapple | fruit

//resulting HTML:
<select>
    <option value="flower">rose</option>
    <option value="fruit">pineapple</option>
</select>

Is there a clean way to make this work (without using Javascript), or should I issue a bug report?
The same settings will produce checkboxes and radio-buttons with same value as expected, but not selects. Selects are also not required by HTML specs to have unique options.
(Please ignore, that duplicate values might not seem too useful to you and might lead to minor problems like displaying chosen option, when going a step back in the form.)
